# How did I manage to mangle my Mac OS X hosts?

Tags: macos, dns, hosts

A while ago I set reddit.com to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts, because it was way too much of a time sink.  I don't remember exactly how I set it - I know I had some trouble with it and tried a few different things before I found the "right" method, so I might have done something weird.

Now, no matter what I do, I can't un-set it or set it to something else - it's somehow "stuck" on 127.0.0.1.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/hosts
Password:
```

I add these two lines:

```
208.96.53.70 reddit.com
208.96.53.70 reddit2.com
```

Save, exit, then:

```
$ dscacheutil -flushcache
$ ping reddit.com
PING reddit.com (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
$ ping reddit2.com
PING reddit2.com (208.96.53.70): 56 data bytes
```

Same thing if I don't specify reddit.com at all.

What am I missing?? I don't have any other entry for reddit.com in my hosts file.  It's not a router or ISP issue - other computers on the same router are fine.  Where else could it be defined?

For the sake of completeness, I cleaned everything out of my hosts, and it contains only the following:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Comment: What IP address does 'dig reddit.com' give you?

Comment: reddit.com.  6 IN A 216.207.68.88
reddit.com.  6 IN A 216.207.68.72

(I got 208.96.53.70 from a google search just for testing, it's likely out of date.)

Comment: Try 'dscacheutil -cachedump -entries host' as an admin. Is reddit.com in there, and if so which DS node was it found in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may've created the host entry in DSLocal, rather than /etc/hosts.  To find out, run:

```
dscl /Search -read /Hosts/reddit.com
```

It should come back with something like this:

```
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
IPAddress: 127.0.0.1
RecordName: reddit.com
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Hosts
```

See the AppleMetaNodeLocation? That tells you where it's getting the info from.  If it says `/BSD/local`, it's in /etc/hosts; if it says `/Local/Default` (which I suspect it will), that's the default local directory node, aka DSLocal.  If it says `<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14136 (eDSRecordNotFound)`, then I have no idea what you've done.

Anyway, assuming the entry is coming from DSLocal, it's fairly easy to remove:

```
sudo dscl /Local/Default -delete /Hosts/reddit.com
```

Comment: Thank you sir - that is exactly it!  Would vote up, but no rep yet :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
ping reddit.com
```

and report back.

Comment: Already did - see above.  As far as I can tell this should do the trick, but it doesn't, that's why I'm baffled.

Comment: Wow, sorry I apparently jumped over that while reading. I'd maybe grep for reddit.com in /etc and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to run

```
sudo niload -v -m hosts . < /etc/hosts
```

after updating your hosts file if you want the changes to take.

Comment: I think that was for older versions of Mac OS X, I'm running 10.5.7 - "command not found" on mine.